# Canadian multilingual standrard keyboard dead key not working

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am using Windows 10 with English US as a primary language. I have also added French Canada language and added Canadian Multilingual Standard keyboard there.
Normally, in CMS layout `[` is a dead key used to type accented letters, e.g. to type `ê`, I would press `[` followed by `e`. However, for some reason when I press `[`, it types `^^` and then the following `e` appears normally without any accent.

Any ideas as to what can be wrong with my setup?

Comment: Actually, I have just noticed that ins some MS applications (e.g. Get Help) it works, but doesn't work in Chrome or Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to close the Perfect Keyboard. If you bring the Perfect Keyboard main window to front (make it active) and then minimize/hide it again then the dead keys should work fine.

Best regards, Petr

Comment: The solution works for ^ and ¨ (ê, ë), but not for ` (ù)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was [PerfectKeyboard](https://www.pitrinec.com/products/perfect-keyboard) software that I was running - when closed, dead keys started to work as expected...